# Docker and node_modules - put them in a layer, or a volume?

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules

I'm planning a docker dev environment and doubtful whether running `npm install` as a cached layer is a good idea.

I understand that there are [ways to optimize dockerfiles to avoid rebuilding node_modules unless package.json changes](http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/), however I don't want to completely rebuild `node_modules` every time `package.json` changes either. A fresh `npm install` takes over 5 minutes for us, and changes to `package.json` happen reasonably frequently. For someone reviewing pull requests and switching branches quite often, they could have to suffer through an infuriating amount of 5 minute `npm installs` each day.

Wouldn't it be better in cases like mine to somehow install `node_modules` into a volume so that it persists across builds, and small changes to `package.json` don't result in the entire dependency tree being rebuilt?

Answer (score 9):

Yes. Don't rebuild `node_modules` over and over again. Just stick them in a data container and mount it read only. You can have a central process rebuild `node_modules` now and then.

As an added benefit, you get a much more predictable build because you can enforce that everyone uses the same node modules. This is critical if you want to be sure that you actually test the same thing that you're planning to put in production.

Something like this (untested!):

```
docker build -t my/module-container - <<END_DOCKERFILE
FROM busybox
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/node
VOLUME /usr/local/node
END_DOCKERFILE

docker run --name=module-container my/module-container

docker run --rm --volumes-from=module-container \
    -v package.json:/usr/local/node/package.json \
    /bin/bash -c "cd /usr/local/node; npm install"
```

By now, the data container `module-container` will contain the modules specified by `package.json` in `/usr/local/node/node_modules`. It should now be possible to mount it in the production containers using `--volume-from=module-container`.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this. Is there a guide that would demonstrate how to set this up? Would you be able to write up a config file to demonstrate this?